# How to get the ipa file for Xamarin ios App if your using Windows OS to connect to Mac OS?

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile, ipa

Hi how to get the **ipa file** for **Xamarin ios App** if your using **Windows os** to **connect to Mac os**?

I'm **not connecting my Mac to device** instead I'm using **Iphone simulator** to **deploy my app** But I do have a **Apple developer account** with **certficates of my app**.

So **what and all is required for getting a ipa file** and how to do it?Actually I build the app in **Ad-hoc mode** and it was **successful** but there was **no ipa file generated in folder**.Does the ipa file get generated in **.ipa extension or some other extension**?

**My Main Question is**. Is it possible to generate ipa file with ios simulator instead of Ios device connected to MAC?

Answer (score 0):

The main answer is yes. I do it this way:

1. startup project IOS - connect to Mac host
2. set Release configuration, Device iPhone (you dont have to connect one to mac)
3. insure in project configuration in iOS IPA Options you have checked Build iTunes Package Archive (leave Include iTunesArtwork UNchecked)
4. insure your bundle signing settings are all set ok: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/#provisioningprovisioningindexmd
5. Build and grab your IPA file from the hidden generated release folder

Comment: Nick Kovalsky will I be able to build my App if the Mac Host I'm connected to has Xcode 8 instead of Xcode 9. Because the documentation u provided me i.e https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/#provisioningprovisioningindexmd suggests that "Xcode 9 introduced the option of deploying to an iOS device or Apple TV through a network, rather than having to hardwire your devices every time you want to deploy and debug your app. This feature is currently in preview".

Comment: I was already doing it when xcode was 8. BUT your xamarin versions between mac and pc must match. And latest VS xamarin will not match with outdated xamarin provided with xcode 8. In theory in latest VS they made it so xamarin uploads its latest dlls to mac if mismatch is detected, but i tested this feature with xcode 9 only.

Comment: This has nothing to do with this thread question pls kindly create another thread

Comment: Unload your Android project and try again. Or excude it from build for this configuration since you'r hopefully building for iOS.